# C++ type coercion deduction

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with the Colvin-Gibbons trick for implementing move semantics in C++03 and I've got the following:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T>
class buffer {
    struct buffer_ref {
        buffer_ref(T* data) : data_(data) {}
        T* data_;
    };

public:
    buffer() : data_(NULL) {}
    //explicit buffer(T* data) : data_(data)        {}
    buffer(size_t size)      : data_(new T[size]) {}
    buffer(buffer_ref other) : data_(other.data_) { other.data_ = NULL; } 
    buffer(buffer    &other) : data_(other.data_) { other.data_ = NULL; }
   ~buffer()                                      { delete [] data_;    }

    operator buffer_ref() { buffer_ref ref(data_); data_ = NULL; return ref; }
    operator T*()         { return data_;                                    }

private:
    T* data_;
};


int main() {
    buffer<float> data(buffer<float>(128));
    printf("ptr: %p\n", (float*)data);

}
```

Edit: formatting

I'd like to be able to use my buffer as a pointer to the base type when convenient, so I've added a casting operator to the pointer type, which works just as expected.  However, if I uncomment my constructor that takes a pointer, then the the conversion deduction gets confused and complains about ambiguous conversion (because it can go buffer->T*->buffer or buffer->buffer_ref->buffer).  I would expect an explicit modifier on the pointer constructor to fix this, but it doesn't.  Can someone who understands the C++ conversion deduction better than me explain what the compilers thinking?

Comment: You could just use an `auto_ptr` with an [adapter for arrays](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/042.htm). It implements the rest for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct result of 13.3.1.3 **[over.match.ctor]**:

> When objects of class type are direct-initialized (8.5), or copy-initialized from an expression of the same or a derived class type (8.5), overload resolution selects the constructor. For direct-initialization, the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized. For copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the converting constructors (12.3.1) of that class. [...]

Because `buffer<float> data(buffer<float>(128));` is a direct-initialization, you have explicitly requested that `explicit` constructors be considered.

If you write:

```
buffer<float> data = buffer<float>(128);
```

then there is no ambiguity.